# How to use TFlite android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

Hello everyone who paid attention!). I'm new to machine learning and stacked with one problem. I have a pretrained image classifier neural network converted to tflite and I want to use it in android studio. In my input is a bitmap from Camera Photo .I used this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/android. Sample code i changed like this

```java
try {

            ConvertedModel model = ConvertedModel.newInstance(this);

            // Creates inputs for reference.
            TensorImage image = TensorImage.fromBitmap(Photo_bitMap);

            // Runs model inference and gets result.
            ConvertedModel.Outputs outputs = model.process(image);
            List<Category> probability = outputs.getProbabilityAsCategoryList();
   
            // Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close();
            //see probability chance
            System.out.println(probability);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
           //catch error 
        }
```

ConvertedModel - IDE automatically found the model and put it. Its my converted model located in ml
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vs5T.png)
But in response,i print probability result and get a completely wrong probability, which I didn't get in pretests before converting. It also gives the same probability for the same image each time it is entered.l.e for example we input white picture, and for this picture probability will be same for any time when we input it, kile const.

My probability wrong cuz i used model incorrectly?
If Im not using the model correctly, why do I get the probability, and  got same probability for same picture?
How to fix this

Answer (score 0):

My code was correct sry, the problem was in my network. I download [this network](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/mobilenet_v1_0.75_160_quantized/1/default/1) with metadata and everything worked.